# Cannot get data from my gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have problems to get the data of a particular cell in my gridview
i'm doing it this way :

```
double total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < GridFactures.Rows.Count; i++)
    total += Convert.ToDouble(GridFactures.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text.ToString());

lblTotalTTC.Text = "Montant total TTC : " + total;
```

The column in question is declared in my aspx file :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Montant TTC">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMontantTTC" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MontantTTC") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

i'm sure this is always the sixth column i want to check.
i put a break and `GridFactures.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text.ToString()`always contains ""
nothing more ... 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken (and your label is the first/only control in the cell) -

You need to ask for the control at index 0, or find it by id, then ask for the .Text

Like so:

```
GridFactures.Rows[i].Cells[6].Controls[0].Text.ToString()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I cannot manage to get any data from the gridview actually.

Comment: For testing purposes, try using the GridFactures.Rows[i].FindControl("lblMontantTTC") method and see if you can find it that way around.

Comment: thanks again but it's not working either... i don't understand

Comment: it displays { text = "40.01" } ( with a spy )
I need to get this value but i cannot get access to the Text Property for instance

Comment: WORKING WITH THIS :

 total = total + Convert.ToDouble(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)(GridFactures.Rows[i].FindControl("lblMontantTTC"))).Text);

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridFactures.Rows.Count; i++)
    total += Convert.ToDouble(GridFactures.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text.ToString());
```

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridFactures.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Control ctrl = GridFactures.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("lblMontantTTC");
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        Label lbl = ctrl as Label;
        if (lbl != null)
        {
            total += Convert.ToDouble(lbl.Text);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remember it is a zero based index, so [6] means cell 7

Comment: hehe a mistake that is made far too often just had to be sure ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know why. I just ran into the same situation myself. You need to check fields that are empty, if so, convert it to zero first.

```
   total += (GridFactures.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text == "")? 0d : Convert.ToDouble(GridFactures.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use LINQ instead of looping?

```
double mySum = 
        GridFactures.Rows
                    .Cast<GridViewRows>()
                    .Sum(row =>  
                Double.Parse(((Label)row.FindControl("lblMontantTTC")).Text));
```

If you're seeing no values, then your grid actually hasn't been databound yet, or ViewState is disabled on the grid. This all depends on where/when you're performing this calculation in the  page lifecycle.